# one to many and many to many mapping in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

one to many and many to many mapping in hibernate. What does this mean.

Comment: Have you tried Google? For your question, it turns up [the relevant chapter of the Hibernate Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html) first of all, then several more examples to such mappings etc...

Comment: @Péter - It's ironic that it takes quite a bit more effort to ask a question than it does to search on Google. Still, onwards and upwards. :-)

Comment: @middaparka, I was thinking about extending my comment along the same line, but I decided to leave the conclusion as an exercise for the OP :-)

Comment: @Peter, imagine the irony that it was a Google search on this subject that brought me to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a fantastically lazy question.

As such, here's a lazy answer: "It's a means of specifying the relationships between objects."

Answer (score 1):

That's the mapping of database tables to each other: 1:n and n:m relationship.

Answer (score 1):

it means the relations between objects, just like in Data Bases